# Disappeared list variable

Tags: python

Could you please tell why list variable have disappeared after "while" cycle?

> ```
> @staticmethod
> def division(f, s):
>     result = []
>     tr = []
>     if len(s) > len(f):
>         return [Polynomial(0), Polynomial(f)]
>
>     while len(f) >= len(s):
>         r = []
>         k = 0
>         mf = 2*f[len(f)-1]
>         ms = 2*s[len(s)-1]
>         m = []
>
>         if mf < 0:
>             mf *= -1
>         if ms < 0:
>             ms *= -1
>
>         if mod(f[len(f)-1], mf) < mod(s[len(s)-1], ms):
>             return [Polynomial(0), Polynomial(f)]
>
>         while mod(f[len(f)-1], mf) >= k:
>             k += mod(s[len(s)-1], ms)
>         k -= mod(s[len(s)-1], ms)
>         r.append([k/mod(s[len(s)-1], ms), len(f)-len(s)])
>         if f[len(f)-1] > 0 and s[len(s)-1] < 0 or f[len(f)-1] < 0 and s[len(s)-1] > 0:
>             r[len(r)-1][0] *= -1
>         for i in xrange(r[len(r)-1][1]+1):
>             m.append(0)
>         m[len(m)-1] = r[len(r)-1][0]
>         result.append(r[len(r)-1])
>
>         subtrahend = Polynomial.multiplication(Polynomial(m).Coefficients,
>         Polynomial(s).Coefficients).Coefficients
>
>         f = Polynomial.subtraction(f, subtrahend).Coefficients
>         print result
>
>     print result
>     o = []
>
>     for i in xrange(result[0][1]+1):
>         o.append(0)
>
>     for i in xrange(len(result)):
>         o[i] = result[i][0]
>     o.reverse()
>
>     if len(f) == 0:
>         f = [0]
>
>     return [Polynomial(o), Polynomial(f)]
> ```

```
f = Polynomial.subtraction(f, subtrahend).Coefficients
    print result

print result
```

First print shows correct result, but second print (after end of cycle) shows nothing. If I try to redefine it like this:

```
f = Polynomial.subtraction(f, subtrahend).Coefficients
    print result
result = 'asdf'
print result
```

nothing happened. Result variable is still None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns *early*:

```
return [Polynomial(0), Polynomial(f)]
```

The code after the `while` loop is never reached if that `return` statement is executed, which happens if `mod(f[len(f)-1], mf) < mod(s[len(s)-1], ms)` is ever `True`.